# The complexity of Steinberg's strip-packing algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis, recursion

In reading the paper "a strip-packing algorithm with absolute performance bound 2", the author gives a recursion formula $T(l)=T(l')+T(l'')+O(min\{l'\log{l'},l''\log{l'}',l\})$, where $l'+l''=l$,$l'>0$,$l''>0$, I'm confused about  the complexity of the recurison formula, how to obtain $T(n)=O(n\log^2(n)/\log\log n)$?
https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/S0097539793255801

Comment: Are $l$, $l'$, $n$ integers?

Comment: yes, all symbols are integers.